# Product Image not showing up in wordpress-woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have WooCommerce & Latest Wordpress setup.
Problem I am facing is the edit product page and product list page in admin side is not showing images.

The reason is that Wordpress admin has HTTPS URL and the images are trying to load from HTTP URL. But I don't know why Wordpress/WooCommerce is trying to load these images using HTTP URL.

I have tried to disable all plugins one-by-one but it doesn't make any difference.
Please help me if anyone have faced same issue or have any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset_meta', '__return_null' );
```

Wordpress now adds extra meta data within images to help with responsiveness, this code will disable that for now.

Found on: http://www.barecode.co/wordpress-woocommerce-broken-images-since-update/

Answer (score 2):

Try change setting here [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfCUQ.png) and change your .htaccess file `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>`

You can reead more [here.](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-ssl-and-https-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Thanks Artyom, I did thought about this but I don't want to make whole site HTTPS

Comment: @Keyur read this post http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-ssl-and-https-in-wordpress/  or this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-force-images-to-https it may help you